# Nonlinear System Dynamic Size

Tags: scipy, sympy

Trying to write a dynamic solver for N points (centers).

`nsolve` returns `matrix is numerically singular` while `scipy` returns `Result from function call is not a proper array of floats`

I have noticed that scipy solver is better at finding solutions than nsolve. Is scipy compatible with sympy? Is there a better way to create variables in Python (perhaps through global())?

I have a feeling that scipy cannot evaluate sympy symbols as variables

```
from sympy import *
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import random

#number of points
centers = 4

#get the right indices for the equations (e.g. Ax, Ay, Bx, By, etc.)
equations = []
for idx, i in enumerate(range(0, (centers-1)*2, 2)):
    for y in range(2 + (idx*2), centers*2, 2):
        equations.append([i, y, i+1, y+1])

#dynamically create variables using sympy.Symbol
vars_list = []
for i in range(0,centers*2):
    vars_list.append(Symbol('x_'+str(i)))
    globals()['x_'+str(i)] = None

#random initial solutions
random_inits = [random.random() for _ in range(0,centers*2)]

#Format: (Ax - Bx)**2 + (Ay - By)**2 - 0.2421875**2
equation_list = []
for item in equations:
    equation_list.append((vars_list[item[0]] - vars_list[item[1]])**2 + (vars_list[item[2]] - vars_list[item[3]])**2 - random.random())
#dummy
for _ in range(0,2):
    equation_list.append((vars_list[item[0]] - vars_list[item[1]])**2 + (vars_list[item[2]] - vars_list[item[3]])**2 - random.random())

#lists lengths match
print (len(equation_list), len(vars_list), len(random_inits))

print(nsolve(equation_list, vars_list, random_inits))

def equations(p):
    vars_list = p
    return equation_list

print(fsolve(equations, random_inits))
```

Comment: As a general rule `numpy/scipy` cannot work directly with `sympy` objects.  Proper numpy arrays are numeric; a numpy array of sympy objects will be object dtype, and slower.  There is a `sympy` `lambdify` that can translate some sympy expressions into `numpy` equivalents.  There are plenty of questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

Before worrying about implementation details, take a look at your equations: your last 3 are duplicates in terms of symbols with different constants...these will not allow a solution:

```
>>> for i in equation_list[-3:]:print(i)
(x_4 - x_6)**2 + (x_5 - x_7)**2 - 0.447608387295936
(x_4 - x_6)**2 + (x_5 - x_7)**2 - 0.523866974100479
(x_4 - x_6)**2 + (x_5 - x_7)**2 - 0.915608644817872
```

What is the problem that you are trying to solve? It looks like finding intersections between circles for which 3 points on each are given.

Comment: fsolve requires equal number of variables, equations, and random intial states. I am trying to find intersections for N circles. The usual solution online is to have dummy equations to meet the requirements of the scipy lib

Comment: Do you want the common intersection of all circles? or just any intersection? If the latter, you would build up the solutions by finding intersections between each pair of circles.